# How do I set AllowOverdrive to all

Tags: apache, raspbian

I want to try to make an .htaccess file so I can do an error file, but I just cannot do it (and I need to allowoverdrive to something. I use a raspberry pi.

Comment: What do you mean by "I just cannot do it"? What is your exact problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be done in the apache configuration file

```
For RedHat/CentOS : /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
For Ubuntu/Debian : /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Assume the web directory where you want to place .htaccess file is /var/www

So between <Directory /var/www> and < /Directory>
put this line:

```
AllowOverride All
```